Type theory reference including applications to multiple computer languages
I'm wondering if anyone could recommend me a good text on the application of type theory to computer languages (plural).
What I'm looking for:

Discusses formal theory in moderately-rigorous terms
Maps formal theory onto a diverse set of applications
Interprets divergence from formal theory in practical contexts (e.g. unsound computer language type systems)

What I am not interested in:

Only works with a single specific, mathematically-inclined computer language (e.g. Haskell)
Only examines "pure" applications, i.e. where the application is intentionally chosen or designed to tightly match the formalism
Omits real-world motivating context for its applications

Anyone know of anything like this?  Cheers.
